# Add default item to ComboBox while binding data with DataSet - WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

My Code to Bind ComboBox in windows forms is like this

```
  ddlUsers.DataSource = dsUsers.Tables[0];
  ddlUsers.ValueMember = "userID";
  ddlUsers.DisplayMember = "Username";
```

I want to add a deafult Item as first element to this ComboBox, I have tried something like this

```
  ddlUsers.Items.Insert(0, "-Select a user-");
```

But it throws an error like this.

```
Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.
```

Can anyone point out correct approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add row in table this way:

```
DataRow newRow = dataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();

newRow["userID"] = 0;
newRow["Username"] = "-Select a User-";

dataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
```

and then give source to combo:

```
 ddlUsers.DataSource = dsUsers.Tables[0];
 ddlUsers.ValueMember = "userID";
 ddlUsers.DisplayMember = "Username";
```

For more information refer [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)cmbControl.DataSource;
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr["UserName"] = "---Select User----";
      dr["UserID"] = "0";

      dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
```

> > Insert row into datatable and use method InsertAt

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the content of dsUsers.Tables[0] to a List first, add your manual item and then bind that List as DataSource instead of dsUsers.Tables[0] directly.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new `Row` at the top.

```
dr = dsUsers.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr[userID] = "0";
dr[Username] = "-Select a User-";
dsUsers.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
```

And you can set your source as usual

```
ddlUsers.DataSource = dsUsers.Tables[0];
ddlUsers.ValueMember = "userID";
ddlUsers.DisplayMember = "Username";
```